# how to send push notifications programmatically using flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to send the push notification using flutter. I have stored the device token into the database. I want to send the push notification to those devices. Is there any way we can send the push notification using php to flutter devices?

Comment: you can check some publications on fcm with flutter here https://medium.com/flutterpub/enabling-firebase-cloud-messaging-push-notifications-with-flutter-39b08f2ed723 and https://codesundar.com/flutter-push-notification

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

 _getId() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) iOSPermission();
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
      updateTable(token); //ADD THIS TOKEN TO YOUR TABLE ,
    });
}

    
void iOSPermission() {
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true)
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings)
    {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
 }
recieveNoti(){
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
       print('on message $message');
       showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            content: ListTile(
              title: Text(message['notification']['title']),
              subtitle: Text(message['notification']['body']),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Ok'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
       print('on resume $message');
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
       print('on launch $message');
      },
    );
 }







//Send Notification:


Future<bool> callOnFcmApiSendPushNotifications({String uid,String newMsg}) async {
    //GET FIREBASE TOKEN ID OF THOSE USER WHICH WANT TO SEND NOTIFICATION 
    var result =  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users').doc(uid).get();

    var token = result.get('pushToken');
    print("SENDERID :$authorId \n NOTIFICATION MESSAGE:$newMsg \nR TOKEN$token");

// You will find SERVER_KEY in your firebase project Setting.

    final headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key=$SERVER_KEY' 
    };

   final response = await http.post(postUrl,
    body: jsonEncode(
      <String, dynamic>{
        'notification': <String, dynamic>{
          'body': '$newMsg',
          'title': 'New message'
        },
        'priority': 'high',
        'data': <String, dynamic>{
          'click_action':
          'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
          'id': '1',
          'status': 'done',
          "screen": "OPEN_NOTIFICATION",
        },
        'to':'$token'
      },
    ),
    encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    headers: headers);
      
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('SENT NOTIFICATION SUCCESSFULLY');
      return true;
    } else {
      print('GETTING EXCEPTION WHILE SENDING NOTIFICATION');
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Here the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) plugin ,that I Have used in one of my project for push notification.